# Is the US constitution based on the religious principles?

Tags: united-states, politics

This site makes the claim: https://donotlink.it/N72k

> Indeed, our second president and co-author of the Declaration of Independence, John Adams, issued a fervent warning to future generations that “Our Constitution was made only for a moral and religious people. It is wholly inadequate to the government of any other.”
>
> The ancient foundation-stone of all modern human rights law in the world today is the Magna Carta, signed in Britain in 1215.  Importantly, that document, too, sets as its first principle “ that the Church of England shall be free, and shall have all her whole Rights and Liberties inviolable.”

Comment: Your quote doesn't include the term "bible." Are you sure you quoted the relevant portion?

Comment: No problem. Seems like you need to further edit your question.

Comment: If you are asking "What motivated the authors of this document?", then the question is about motivation of individuals and [is explicitly off-topic](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/621/politics-beliefs-and-motivations-questions-should-not-be-allowed-here). If your question is more a post-modern interpretation of the text, then it is opinion-based.

Comment: There are only three [parts of Magna Carta which have not been repealed](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/aep/Edw1cc1929/25/9/contents): the liberties of the  Church of England, the liberties of London, and no imprisonment or confiscation contrary to law.  The first was to protect the church leadership from the king, a reference to King John's father's battle with Thomas Becket; it did not suggest that the English people were particularly moral or religious

Comment: He's signalling that virtue is the necessary ingredient for democracy to work.  You can read Montesquieu or Tocqueville for more.